# Ingresar numeros binarios desde el teclado

Tags: java, binario, funcion

Saludos Gurus de Java

Me pueden ayudar con esta consulta para ingresar datos desde el teclado como puedo restirngir que el numero sea solo binario y si no es binario le de un mensaje ejemplo:

Si queira ingresar 10101011111 si me deje pero si ya trae un numero diferente a 1 y 0 como 14050111 que envie un mensaje.

Gracias

Comment: Maneja el dato ingresado como String y usa charAt() `for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char caracter = num.charAt(i);
            if(caracter!='0'&&caracter!='1'){                
                System.out.println("Ingresar sólo 1 o 0");}`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres almacenar el valor directamente como entero puedes pasarle al Scanner el entero 2 `nextInt(2)` para indicarle que sera un Input Binario, esto regresa automáticamente error si no es binario.

Importando primero el Scanner a tu proyecto.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Y solicitando la información como binaria.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int binaryNumber = scanner.nextInt(2);
System.out.println(binaryNumber);
```

Si quieres almacenarlo como string entonces para validar que solo sean 0 y 1 ocupas crear una función para validar el string.

```
String binaryNumberString = scanner.next();
        
        for(int i=0; i<binaryNumberString.length(); i++){
            if(binaryNumberString.charAt(i) != '0' && binaryNumberString.charAt(i) != '1'){
                System.out.println("El valor no es binario");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya con eso logré hacer el metodo de validación